# Convert a vector into binary tree in Rust

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust. One exercise I am doing is to convert Java code I wrote into Rust. This code aims to convert an vector into binary tree in the order like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

              1 
            /   \
           2     3
          / \   / \
         4   5 6   7
```

The Rust code I wrote is like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TreeNode<T> {
    pub value: T,
    pub left: Option<Box<TreeNode<T>>>,
    pub right: Option<Box<TreeNode<T>>>
}


pub fn construct_tree<T: Copy>(input: Vec<Option<T>>) -> Option<Box<TreeNode<T>>> {
    match input.len() {
        0 => None,
        1 => {
            if input[0].is_none() {
                panic!("Cannot have one single None as input.");
            }

            let node: TreeNode<T> = TreeNode {
                value: input[0].unwrap().clone(),
                left: None,
                right: None
            };

            Some(Box::new(node))
        },
        _ => {
            let mut tree: Vec<Option<Box<TreeNode<T>>>> = input
                .into_iter()
                .map(|x| x.map(|value| Box::new(TreeNode {
                    value,
                    left: None,
                    right: None,
                })))
                .collect();

            let len = tree.len();
            for i in 0..len {
                let left_child_index = 2 * i + 1;
                let right_child_index = 2 * i + 2;

                let left = if left_child_index < len {tree[left_child_index].take()} else {None};
                let right = if right_child_index < len {tree[right_child_index].take()} else {None};

                if let Some(ref mut node) = tree[i] {
                    if left_child_index < len {
                        node.left = left;
                    }
                    if right_child_index < len {
                        node.right = right;
                    }
                }
            }

            tree.into_iter().nth(0).unwrap_or(None)
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let tree1 = construct_tree(vec![Some(3),Some(9),Some(20)]);
        println!("{:?}", tree1.unwrap());  // This works

        let tree2 = construct_tree(vec![Some(3),Some(9),Some(20), Some(15), Some(7)]);
        println!("{:?}", tree2.unwrap());  // This does not work.
    }
}
```

It only works for an array with up to 3 elements, but not for one with more than 3 elements. I think this is due to the take() method I call on the tree.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: { pro tips: ["don't do linked list in Rust (using self referential structure)."] }

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @Stargateur: This doesn’t appear to be a self-referential structure.

Comment: @possum OP has stated the problem they are trying to solve, their attempt and the point where they are stuck. All of these make this question infinitely better than “do my job for me while I go have a beer” type questions that plague Stackoverflow these days.

Comment: I suggest you take your complaint to the thread I posted then.

Comment: @possum I’m not complaining, I’m informing you that the thread you linked to isn’t relevant.

Comment: This is same algorithm as "iterating" a binary tree.  Only you add nodes instead of enumerating them.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar It was when I posted.  That was literally the question

Comment: @Ry- `TreeNode` contains a `TreeNode` that what I call self referential structure even if there is no a real "reference" I group them together, that still a bad data structure for language like rust.

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is due to the take() method I call on the tree.

That’s right: you’re taking the children that you want to visit later with the loop in order to construct their parents.

> How can I fix this problem?

Loop backwards, so you only take the nodes you’ve already visited:

```
for i in (0..len).rev() {
```

By the way: the way you’ve written it, there’s no need to special-case 0 or 1, or to require `T` to be `Copy`.

```
pub fn construct_tree<T>(input: Vec<Option<T>>) -> Option<Box<TreeNode<T>>> {
    let mut tree: Vec<Option<Box<TreeNode<T>>>> = input
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.map(|value| Box::new(TreeNode {
            value,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })))
        .collect();

    let len = tree.len();
    for i in (0..len).rev() {
        let left_child_index = 2 * i + 1;
        let right_child_index = 2 * i + 2;

        let left = tree.get_mut(left_child_index).and_then(Option::take);
        let right = tree.get_mut(right_child_index).and_then(Option::take);

        if let Some(ref mut node) = tree[i] {
            if left_child_index < len {
                node.left = left;
            }
            if right_child_index < len {
                node.right = right;
            }
        }
    }

    tree.into_iter().nth(0).flatten()
}
```